# How to retrieve or create a list of things from wordnet - animals, household items or names?

Tags: python, pandas, python-itertools, wordnet, praw

I currently have a Pandas dataframe scraped from reddit.com/r/cryptomoonshots with the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([vars(post) for post in reddit.subreddit('cryptomoonshots').hot(limit=100)])
df = df[["title","score","url"]]
df.head()
```

That produces a readable df:

```
    title                                               score
3   Valor Game Token | Next X100 Gems | Insane Mar...   1135
4   Legends of Aragon token launch | NFT Game is a...   1085
5   TetheRhino Tomorrow Presale 16:00 UTC on DxSal...   833
6   GYM NETWORK The First DeFi Aggregator With Int...   442
7   Puli (PULI) is taking the BSC scene by storm! ...   1482
```

Since the first 1-3 words of any of these posts describes the coin itself being shilled, I want to pair them up with a list of things and then classify them accordingly. E.g., 'Beagle Coin' would be find as part of a string in a list containing called Dogs = ['Beagle', etc.]

The iteration part is not hard, but how would we generate a list of things to match these with?

I tried with wordnet and itertools:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
from itertools import chain
dogs = list(chain(*[i.lemma_names for i in wn.all_synsets() if "dog" in i.definition]))
```

but it gave me the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-7da682828270> in <module>
      1 from itertools import chain
----> 2 dogs = list(chain(*[i.lemma_names for i in wn.all_synsets() if "dog" in i.definition]))

<ipython-input-33-7da682828270> in <listcomp>(.0)
      1 from itertools import chain
----> 2 dogs = list(chain(*[i.lemma_names for i in wn.all_synsets() if "dog" in i.definition]))

TypeError: argument of type 'method' is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0):

`definition` in the failing line of your code is a method, not an instance variable of some iterable type. The `if "dog" in i.definition` part of your code fails as the `in` clause expects an iterable. ***Invoking*** the `definition` method should fix the error. And if you are looking to get a  list of strings as the `dogs` object, you would need to ***invoke*** the `lemma_names` method too. So your list comprehension line should be:

```
dogs = list(chain(*[i.lemma_names() for i in wn.all_synsets() if "dog" in i.definition()]))
```